# Keras Conv2D: filters vs kernel_size

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What's the difference between those two? It would also help to explain in the more general context of convolutional networks.

Also, as a side note, what is channels? In other words, please break down the 3 terms for me: channels vs filters vs kernel.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each convolution layer consists of several convolution channels (aka. depth or filters). In practice, they are a number such as `64, 128, 256, 512` etc. This is equal to number of channels in the output of a convolutional layer. `kernel_size`, on the other hand, is the size of these convolution filters. In practice, they take values such as `3x3` or `1x1` or `5x5`. To abbreviate, they can be written as `1` or `3` or `5` as they are mostly square in practice.

**Edit**

Following quote should make it more clear.

[Discussion on vlfeat](https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/issues/457)

Suppose `X` is an input with size `W x H x D x N` (where `N` is the size of the batch) to a convolutional layer containing filter `F` (with size `FW x FH x FD x K`) in a network.

The number of feature channels `D` is the third dimension of the input `X` here (for example, this is typically 3 at the first input to the network if the input consists of colour images).
The number of filters `K` is the fourth dimension of `F`.
The two concepts are closely linked because if the number of filters in a layer is `K`, it produces an output with K feature channels. So the input to the next layer will have `K` feature channels.

The `FW x FH` above is filter size you are looking for.

**Added**

You should be familiar with  [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)). You can consider each filter to be responsible for extracting some type of feature from a raw image. The CNNs try to learn such filters i.e. the filters parametrized in CNNs are learned during training of CNNs. You apply each filter in a Conv2D to each input channel and combine these to get output channels. So, the number of filters and the number of output channels are the same.

Comment: So channels and filters and depth all mean the same thing?

Comment: Just to make sure, FW above is a single new variable, it's not like F*W, right?

Comment: Yeah, FW is width of filter and FH is height of filter.

Comment: So, in the input, the 3 channels have clear meanings, R,G,B values. But in the hidden values, sometimes we have more than 3 channels, what are their meanings? Also, can a value in a single hidden neuron incorporate values from multiple input channels (e.g. both R and B), or there's no "mixing" between the input channels through the convolution process?

Comment: I modified above for interpretation of filters.